wkhtmltopdf keeps on loading for larger HTML input
I'm using PHP Spiritix\HtmlToPdf\Converter(wkhtmltopdf) to convert an HTML page into a PDF. My single HTML page content generates around 240 pages in a PDF, all provided through a single URL input.
However, when the page count exceeds 220, the application hangs and keeps on loading and its never ending.
I've tried various options such as --enable-javascript, --no-stop-slow-scripts, --javascript-delay, and --window-status 'readyToPrint', but none seem to resolve the issue.
Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

PHP generates PDF for 220 pages but not for more than that. Also I am facing issue while generating the PDF not while printing

Although not what you are asking for, I have worked a lot with PDFs over the decades, and have generally had much greater success in creating individual PDFs in a first pass, and merging them in a second pass. Creation can even be parallelized, if not now, then some day in the future. But individual PDFs guarantee that errors in earlier documents won't "spill over" to later documents.

@ChrisHaas: I  want to create a single PDF with 240 pages, here facing loading issues and this loading never ends. What's your advice on this

@ChrisHaas: Do you mean to create 240 single files and then to merge them

@ManiMuthuPandi, yes. Rendering anything of significant length can be troublesome, be it HTML, PDF, or whatever. Because it is one giant thing, sometimes everything needs to be kept in memory so you run in OOM issues. So break it into smaller steps. Merging PDFs is fairly trivial and linear. It also isn't that hard to add "page 1 of 240" in a second/third pass, too, if that's desired.
